# AngularJS - Set background color on select ngOptions of select

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Please see my plunkr below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jEe1PQMP8TLdeOetJ1Yk?p=preview

Here is what my $scope.possibleDates look like

```
$scope.possibleDates = [  
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2016-12-07T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"December - Week 1",
      "allocated":20,
      "capacity":11
   },
   {  
      "projectedStartDate":"2016-12-14T00:00:00",
      "dateName":"December - Week 2",
      "allocated":20,
      "capacity":11
   },...]
```

Here is what my table with the select looks like

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>                 
        <tr>
            <th >List Of Dates</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
            <td>
                <select class="form-control"
                    ng-model="d.projectedStart"
                    ng-options="dates.projectedStartDate as dates.dateName for dates in possibleDates">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>                                               
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to color each options in the dropdown list depending on weather the 'allocated' is greater than 'capacity' or not.

I have tried this but it does not work.

```
ng-class="{overallocated: dates.allocated > dates.capacity, underallocated = dates.allocated > dates.capacity}"
```

Comment: use https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select to set background-color of selected options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```html
 <select ng-model="d.projectedStart">
     <option ng-class="{overallocated: dates.capacity >dates.allocated, underallocated: dates.capacity <dates.allocated}" 
             ng-repeat="dates in possibleDates" >{{dates.dateName}}
     </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: this wont work for me as it does not leave one of the values selected as I have in my plunkr example.  The ng-model on the select creates a blank option which i want to avoid

Comment: wait I will check

Comment: Thanks..thats doing what I want it to do.